# What do the subscripts in expectations mean in loss function

Tags: machine-learning, expected-value, loss-functions

Can someone explain me what this equation means? I read it from page 152 on [deeplearningbook.org](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$J$ is a function respect to the parameter $\theta$. It is "cost function", where our ultimate goal is trying to reduce this the value function by using appropriate $\theta$. $\theta$ is also called "weights", "coefficients", "decision variables", where machine learning is finding the right value for $\theta$.

**First Let's look at the first part of the equation.**

The cost function $J$ comes from two things, the **true distribution** of data and label $P(x,y)$ and the loss function of $L$. The cost function is integrating all the possible values for the true distribution $P(x,y)$, and the Loss.

More about the loss function $L$. I think the name is confusing because we have both "cost function" and "loss function". Here is the differences: $J$ is a cost that for **all of the data points**. and $L$ is the loss **for each predicted value and label**. The loss function $L$, has $3$ inputs. $(x, y)$ and $\theta$. In many cases, we use $\hat y=f(x,\theta)$ to represent predicted value, and $L(y,\hat y)$ to represent the loss value.

**The second part of the equation**

In real world, we will not know the **true distribution** of data and label, i.e., $P(x,y)$. What we can do, is using data to "minimize the empirical loss". Which is $\frac 1 m$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m$ part, assuming we have $m$ data points.

---

Everything will be more clear with an numerical example. Here is one (discrete on $x$ and $y$). Suppose our **true distribution** on data $x$ and label $y$ is (think about $x$ is if it is cloudy, and $y$ is if it will rain.)
$$
P(x=0,y=0)=0.3
$$
$$
P(x=0,y=1)=0.1
$$
$$
P(x=1,y=0)=0.2
$$
$$
P(x=1,y=1)=0.4
$$

And the loss function is $L$ is 0-1 loss. The cost would be

$$\sum_x\sum_yP(x,y)L(y,\hat y)$$

That is the first part of the equation.

For second part: in real world, we will not know the true distribution of $P(x,y)$, but have many data points of $(x_i,y_i)$, what we do is trying to minimize

$$\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^m L(y_i,\hat y_i)$$

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what the notation $\mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{x},y\sim\hat{p}_{data}}$ means, as that is the question in the title.

Comment: We do not know the true distribution in the real world, so we completely omit that term as if it doesn't exist?!

Answer (score 3):

It means that this is the distribution under which the expectation is taken.

More formally:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)}\big[~f(x)~\big] := \int q(x) f(x)  dx.
$$

If clear from the context, the argument to the distribution is often omitted, i.e. 
$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim q}[f(x)]$