# What does this loss function mean?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, loss-functions

I had a interview on deep learning internship job yesterday, and the interviewer showed a loss function formula(below) and asked me 2 questions:

\begin{equation}
J(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}_{x,y\sim\hat{p}_{data}}\log{p_{model}(y|x)}
\end{equation}

1. How to understand $p(y|x)$ in the formula above?
2. On what task does this loss function used for?

Since I have no idea on this loss function, how to answer these 2 questions?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but I think my answer should be good for you. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241380/what-do-the-subscripts-in-expectations-mean-in-loss-function/241385#241385

Comment: As reproduced the loss function is meaningless since there is no $\theta$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since $J(\theta)$ is a function of $\theta$, $p_{model}(y|x)$ should be understood as the **likelihood function** of $\theta$, where $\theta$ is the model parameters, IMO.
2. Therefore this loss is used for maximum likelihood estimation (MLE).

---

Say we have a neural network that takes in $x$ and outputs $f_\theta(x)$, and we assume a Gaussian noise for $y\sim N(f_\theta(x), \sigma^2)$, then $p_{model}(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(y-f_\theta(x))^2}{2\sigma^2})$, then $$J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\frac{1}{m}\sum (y-f_\theta(x))^2+constant$$
minimizing $J(\theta)$ in this case equals to minimizing our favorite mean-squared-error.

Comment: Where is $\theta$ in your likelihood?

Comment: @Xi'an right, maybe it's left out intentionally for the question?

Comment: A question that is intentionally making no mathematical sense?! In your answer, would you consider $\theta$ as implicitly contained in $p(y|x)$ or anything else? For instance, what does $\theta$ stand for in the Normal example?

Comment: @Xi'an ... oops I wasn't prepared for all these questions, but surely I can improve the notation a bit.